# error on loop array of days

Tags: vba, excel

I test this code to loop if one date is into my array.
with the example on the column A, nothing problem,
the result message is 3 and in the immediate window I saw (01/01/2015,06/01/2015,02/02/2015)
to test some case when only 1 day is into array, I delete the 2 day (A3,A4) like column C.
the result message is 1 but i received error on rule `For Each i In arfest` (error runtime 13, type not corresponding)
and if I delete also the value on A2, I retrieve the msg with 1 and the same error previous example.

[image]

```
Sub dada_click()
    Dim arfest As Variant
    Dim i As Variant
    UR = Sheets("Fest").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If UR < 2 Then UR = 2
    arfest = Sheets("Fest").Range("A2:A" & UR)
    MsgBox (Application.CountA(arfest))
    For Each i In arfest
       Debug.Print i
    Next i
End Sub
```

What's wrong?!?!?
thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only 1 object in your range, set a break point on your loop start.  You'll see that arfest is a single date.  There's nothing to loop through. This highlights one of the issues of dimming everything as a variant and letting the compiler decide what the variable is holding.  Be more specific in your declaration.  If you know arfest is a range, tell the compiler that!  Same goes for i.  Try this and see if it gets you past your issue:

```
Sub test()
    Dim arfest As Range
    Dim i As Range
    UR = Sheets("Fest").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If UR < 2 Then UR = 2
    Set arfest = Sheets("Fest").Range("A2:A" & UR)

    For Each i In arfest
       Debug.Print i
    Next i
End Sub
```

Again, step through the my code and your code and see the difference in how arfest is handled in each situation.

Comment: ya it's right, for me stupidly an array is a variant, but is actually correct to define it, I'll make a node. Thank.